# Emacs Lisp error "Wrong type argument: commandp"

Tags: emacs, command, key-bindings

What is wrong with the following code:

```
(defun test
  (interactive)
  (message "hello"))
(global-set-key '[f4]  'test)
```

When evaluating this with `eval-region` and then pressing <kbd>F4</kbd> I get the error:

```
Wrong type argument: commandp, test
```

Comment: Try `(defun test () ...)` with an empty parameter list.

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you very much! You may give it as an answer, and I will accept it..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are missing the argument list of your `test` function, so Emacs interprets the `(interactive)` form as the arglist. Thus you have defined a non-interactive function of 1 argument instead of interactive command of no arguments.

What you want is:

```
(defun test ()
  "My command test"
  (interactive)
  (message "hello"))
```

Lessons learned:

1. Always add a doc string - if you did, Emacs would have complained
2. Use `elint` (comes with Emacs, try <kbd>C-h a elint RET</kbd>).